# PowerShell Install-Module Error - No Match was found for specified search criteria and module name 'PackageManagement'

Tags: powershell, package-management, powershellget

I am trying to run the following command in my Windows 10 PC , and PowerShell version 7.1.2

```
> Install-Module PowerShellGet, PackageMAnagement -Force -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

But I am getting the below error as shown in the screenshot :

-- No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'PackageManagement'.

**Note** : I am trying to run this command on my Office laptop and it is giving me this error. The same thing if I run on my personal PC , this is working fine.

I am really stuck on this for past 4 days. Please help

[image]

Edit :

If I request modules separately , that works .

Meaning , the below works fine ..

> Install-Module PowerShellGet -Force -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
> Install-Module PackageManagement -Force -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

[image]

Comment: I suspect your corproate proxy or firewall is blocking PSGallery

Comment: How can I check that ?

Comment: Please see my Edit . I'm able to  install  'PowerShellGet'  and  'PackageManagement'  separatly

Answer (score 1):

If you have an authenticating proxy you'll need to account for that - Powershell does not look at the system proxy settings by default.

Try adding this before you request the module:

```
    [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()
    [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

If, as the error message suggests, you type `Get-PSRepository` then it should return PSGallery without error if you have a connection

Comment: i have the connections .

Comment: > Get-PSRepository

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
PSGallery                 Untrusted            https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2

Comment: What do you get if you run this: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409" -TimeoutSec 8 -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {$_.StatusCode} `

Comment: I  get   200   when i run this

Comment: As per you edit above - you should pipe values to Install-Module, not supply a comma seperated list.

Comment: You mean like this  :  Install-Module PowerShellGet | PackageManagement -Force -WarningAction SilentlyContinue